# Google Form Response Sheet script that triggers copy of a template spreadsheet to a new filename

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created:

1. Google Sheet as a Master Template ("QC_MasterTemplate") in my root drive that has all formatting as I want for a Checklist to be completed for every new sales order taken.
2. Google Form to collect the new customer name, id and date order was received that our salespersons will use to submit their response.
3. Google Sheet linked to Form storing new order Responses. I also have a my script running on Form Submit of new entry to this sheet that collects the last row entry information.

What I need help with:

The script in the Response Sheet is working to trigger my notification email that a new entry has been made and it breaks down the details of each cell to format in the message of the email just fine.

I'm trying to automate the next step that takes the new entry information to be used in formatting a new Spreadsheet filename. (ie. "companyname-customerid-orderdate-QCChecklist") This variable is easy to build, the problem I'm having is then getting the Response Sheet script to take the non-currently active spreadsheet ("QC_MasterTemplate") and make a copy in the same root location with the new filename

The code I'm using is:

```
function createNewSheet() {
  // Get Template Filename
  var TemplateFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("QC_MasterTemplate");
  // Get current spreadsheet for information lookup
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // Last row of data to process
  var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Starting Column of data to process
  var startColumn = 1;
  // Number of rows to process
  var numRows = 1;
  // Number of columns to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // Get range of cells in columns A:E for all rows with entries
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
  // Get entries for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  // Set each value to a unique variable
  for (i in data) {
    var cell = data[i];
    var timestamp = cell[0];
    var companyname = cell[1];
    var customerid = cell[2];
    var orderdate = cell[3];
    var employee = cell[4];
    // Build body of email
    var subject = companyname + "-" + customerid + "-" + orderdate + " - QC Checklist";
    var message = 'New QC Checklist Form Received \n' +
      '\nTimestamp: ' + timestamp +
      '\nCompany Name: ' + companyname +
      '\nCompany ID: ' + customerid +
      '\nOrder Date: ' + orderdate +
      '\nEmployee Name: ' + employee;
    var recipient = "username@gmail.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message); 
    // Make copy of Template to new filename
    subject.makeCopy(TemplateFile);
  }
}
```

The error I get is:
TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object Striker-37188-20150401 - QC Checklist. (line 39, file "Code")

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can get the parent folder for the spreadsheet(QC_MasterTemplate), go to that folder and create the new spreadsheet file.

In order to get the root folder of the spreadsheet(QC_MasterTemplate) you can use [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents()) method from DriveApp.

Also for creating a spread sheet you have to use [create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)) method.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable named `subject` is a string.  There is no `makeCopy()` method to make a file from a string.  Google Apps Services are object oriented programming.  You need to start at the top, then work your way down to the method.  There is a `makeCopy()` method:

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String))

But you can't just use that method on anything.  For that particular documentation, the `makeCopy()` method only works on the File Class.  So you first need to get a reference to a file.

There are probably multiple ways you can make a copy of the template.

One option is to use the Class DriveApp.

```
function makeCopyOfTemplate() {
  var templateID = 'The File ID of the File'; //Template File ID
  var workingCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy();
  var workingFileID = workingCopy.getId();

  var fileNameToUse = 'CustomerABC Todays Date';
  //Set the file name of the copy file
  workingCopy.setName(fileNameToUse);

  //Open the new copy of the Template
  var workingCopyOfTemplateFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(workingFileID);

  //To Do:  Inject copy with data
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I also realized part of my issue was that I did not have 'The File ID of the File' correctly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Could one also use the `.makeCopy(name, destination)` method thusly?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lmName = (ss.getName() + "_2016-11");
var lmfoldername = ('2016-11-Update');
var lmFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(lmfoldername).next(); 
DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(lmName, lmFolder);
```